# Can you define nested structs/unions in Ruby Fiddle?

Tags: ruby, winapi, struct, union, ffi

I'm using Fiddle to make some Win32 system calls. However, I'm not finding any documentation on how one can define a signature to a struct that contains nested structs or unions.

Is this at all possible? Is there any examples anywhere? All I find is references to how to declare flat structs with basic types.

Example struct:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366798(v=vs.85).aspx

```
typedef struct _PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY {
  PVOID lpData;
  DWORD cbData;
  BYTE  cbOverhead;
  BYTE  iRegionIndex;
  WORD  wFlags;
  union {
    struct {
      HANDLE hMem;
      DWORD  dwReserved[3];
    } Block;
    struct {
      DWORD  dwCommittedSize;
      DWORD  dwUnCommittedSize;
      LPVOID lpFirstBlock;
      LPVOID lpLastBlock;
    } Region;
  };
} PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY, *LPPROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY;
```